# What is the use of extending model class with Equatable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class PushOtpResponse extends Equatable {
  final bool? isSuccess;
  final String? message;

  const PushOtpResponse({this.isSuccess, this.message});

  factory PushOtpResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PushOtpResponse(
      isSuccess: json['isSuccess'] as bool?,
      message: json['message'] as String?,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'isSuccess': isSuccess,
        'message': message,
      };

  @override
  bool get stringify => true;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [isSuccess, message];
}
```

The model class given above is created using json to dart extension of VSCode. There is an option for extending the class with equatable. So, is there any use in extending a model class with equatable and is there any help 'stringify' can do here.

Comment: It's just to trigger another state whether Bloc or Riverpod.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to just read the documentation of Equatable. Equatable is not a default class of flutter, and whoever added that code to your project must have deliberately included the package

https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Answer (score 0):

Equatable overrides == and hashCode without the need for code generation or even writing the code yourself.

With Equatable you can

```
    final resp = PushOtpResponse(
      isSuccess: true,
      message: 'Test',
    );
    final resp2 = PushOtpResponse(
      isSuccess: true,
      message: 'Test',
    );

    resp == resp2; // True with Equatable, False without
```

for more details you can read the documentation of equitable
https://pub.dev/packages/equatable